# get hidden input[type=hidden] in different column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some minor issue about how to get hidden input field in different column. Below is my code just for your reference.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed" id="table_data">
        <thead class="header">
            <tr class="well">
                <th>Header 1</th>
                <th>Header 2</th>
                <th>Header 3</th>
                <th>Header 4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" id="changesID" value="no" />A</td>
                <td id='1'>B</td>
                <td>C</td>
                <td>D</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" id="changesID" value="no" />E</td>
                <td id='2'>F</td>
                <td>G</td>
                <td>H</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" id="changesID" value="no" />I</td>
                <td id='3'>J</td>
                <td>K</td>
                <td>L</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('table').on( 'click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {

        var id = $(this).attr('id');                
        console.log(id)
    });
});
```

When I click on 2nd column it should display id and hidden input fields that located at first column

```
1
no
```

Anyone got idea ?Any help will greatly appreciate. Thank you
https://jsfiddle.net/ash_systm/05y977vf/

Comment: _"When I click on 2nd column it should display id and hidden input fields that located at first column"_ Are you trying to exclude first `tr` from click handler, though log first `tr` `input` values at click of second `tr`? Note, `id` in `document` should be unique; there are duplicate `changesID` `id`'s at `html` at Question

Comment: can you be a bit more specific about the expected output. `"When I click on 2nd column it should display id and hidden input fields that located at first column"`

Comment: @Iceman when I click on 2nd column ,It will display the value id in 2nd column and value hidden field in first column . So in console.log() when I click first rows,on 2nd column it will show 1,no

Comment: @art see my answer. is this what u expected? `$(this).prev().children()[0].value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).prev().children()[0].value
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('table').on('click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(id)
    var val = $(this).prev().children()[0].value;
    console.log(val)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed" id="table_data">
  <thead class="header">
    <tr class="well">
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
      <th>Header 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" id="changesID" value="no" />A</td>
      <td id='1'>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" id="changesID" value="no" />E</td>
      <td id='2'>F</td>
      <td>G</td>
      <td>H</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" id="changesID" value="no" />I</td>
      <td id='3'>J</td>
      <td>K</td>
      <td>L</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: why it show this error gen_files:797 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined @Iceman

Comment: which column did u click @art

Comment: @art its working when i clicked the 2nd column on the "run code snippet"

Comment: sorry my bad ..do you know how to set a new value in the same textfield

Comment: set it directly, like `$(this).prev().children()[0].value="10";`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118185/discussion-between-art-and-iceman).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("tr").click(function(){
            var id          = $(this).children().next().attr('id');
            var hiddenVal   = $(this).children().find('#changesID').val();
            console.log(id);
            console.log(hiddenVal);
        });
    });
```

It will work

Answer (score 0):

better is not use multiple element with same id, some changes in html and javascript. try this code:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" id="changesID" class="changeId" value="no" />A</td>
    <td class="idCol" id='1'>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" id="changesID" class="changeId" value="no" />E</td>
    <td id='2'>F</td>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>H</td>
</tr>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('table tbody tr').on( 'click', 'td:not(:first-child)', function (event) {

    var changeCol = $(event.delegateTarget).find(".changeCol");
    var idCol= $(event.delegateTarget).find(".idCol");

    var id = $(idCol).attr('id');                
    console.log(id)

    var change = $(changeCol).attr('id');                
    console.log(change)
});
```

});